# Count occurrences across columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, find-occurrences

I want to update a column based on the occurrences of values in multiple columns.

SQL Server 2017 schema setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Part varchar(10),Jan int,Feb int,Mar int,Apr int,Occurrences int)

INSERT INTO Table1 (Part,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,Occurrences)VALUES('AAA',null,2,null,1,null),
                                                ('BBB',2,3,5,7,null),
                                                ('CCC',3,null,null,null,null),
                                                ('DDD',4,7,1,null,null)
```

I want to update the Occurrences column based on the values existing in Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr columns. It should skip the null occurrences and count only if value exists.

For the above schema the occurrences column should be updated as

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Update Table1 set
    Occurrences = ISNUMERIC(jan) + ISNUMERIC(feb) + ISNUMERIC(mar) + ISNUMERIC(apr)
```

Comment: @ red devil. How can I make the query dynamic so that the month name jan,feb,mar,etc. is not specified in the update statement? Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Maximize the use of `iif()` function.

```
update table1 set Occurrences = iif(coalesce(Jan, 0) != 0, 1, 0) 
+  iif(coalesce(Feb, 0) != 0, 1, 0) 
+  iif(coalesce(Mar, 0) != 0, 1, 0) 
+  iif(coalesce(Apr, 0) != 0, 1, 0);
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6f71409814e9298077660e14f81c1d1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unpivot` to do that, but additionally you need to pass number of columns you have (`4 - ...` in query):

```
SELECT Part, 4 - COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM @Table1
    UNPIVOT (MonthVal FOR [Month] IN (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)) AS unpvt
) a GROUP BY Part
```